# A beginners guide to Server programming with java

Tags: java

First of all, I'm not new to java but I'm new to JavaWEB and Java server. So.. I'm creating a game that will manipulate data from an existing database.

The problem is: I don't know where to start from since I know nothing about these things.

I want to create a server side that will manipulate data for more than one player (take Minecraft server, for example)

So my question is:

**What should I read first?
Where should I start?**

Some tutorials, texts, guides would be nice. Remember: I'm a noob atmo

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037487/how-to-start-coding-and-setting-up-a-web-server-with-java , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122313/looking-for-a-java-server-tutorial , etc.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like good start:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html

just google some things, during reading, that you have low knowledge at